# angular runtime, styles and polyfiles get a 404 error on my web server

Tags: javascript, angular, http-status-code-404

I have made a little Angular application, I have built it on my computer, but when I try to open the index.html file I have 404 errors, I tried to deploy it on a web server but it's the same  :

GET http://www.valhatech.com/runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET http://www.valhatech.com/styles.365933d9cb35ac99c497.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET http://www.valhatech.com/polyfills-es2015.2987770fde9daa1d8a2e.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

My index.html file is that :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>McKenzieEquation</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

And the content of my app.module.ts is :

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'home', component: AppComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MckenzieGraphComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,FormsModule,RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ],
  providers: [MckenzieEquationService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Firefox console send me on a Reason: CORS request not HTTP error or URI of module source is not authorized in this document : « file:///polyfills-es2015.2987770fde9daa1d8a2e.js ».

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have found my error. On my web server my angular page was located to the following path :
/www/mckenzieequation

And my index file was written like that :

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>McKenzieEquation</title>
  <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

I have to replace the base parameter with the following code :

```
<base href="/mckenzieequation/">
```

The base href must pointing to the place of the index file.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue after I have upgraded from Angular 12 -> 13. And I already have set my base href in index.html to the correct path. 

For some reason it just stopped working after I upgraded Angular :(

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that app-root wasn't inside body tag

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue after updating to Angular `17.1.1`. I switched back to `17.0.5` and `main.js`, `polyfill.js`, etc were again properly served when running `ng serve`.